# Google Cloud Run - Docker building container building but not accessible

Tags: angular, docker, nginx, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-run

New to GCR. I've set up continuous deployment going from my repo. The image get's built just fine without any errors logged to the GCR console, I get a passing build. But when I try and view my active container online via their URL link, it says that the build has failed. Totally confused on what I should be doing! Can anyone help me out please? my dockerfile is below, and to the best of my knowledge the file works as intended. But I am still a noob.

Cloud build logs:

```
   starting build "3e8d7c0f-57ca-4a9f-b30d-d49d364ab286"

    FETCHSOURCE
    hint: Using 'master' as the name for the initial branch. This default branch name
    hint: is subject to change. To configure the initial branch name to use in all
    hint: of your new repositories, which will suppress this warning, call:
    hint: 
    hint:   git config --global init.defaultBranch <name>
    hint: 
    hint: Names commonly chosen instead of 'master' are 'main', 'trunk' and
    hint: 'development'. The just-created branch can be renamed via this command:
    hint: 
    hint:   git branch -m <name>
    Initialized empty Git repository in /workspace/.git/
    From https://source.developers.google.com/p/swift-media-322516/r/github_lewismorgans_portfolio
     * branch            79c27520b788b3631ca0eece3a6107502df402ed -> FETCH_HEAD
    HEAD is now at 79c2752 change exposed port
    BUILD
    Already have image (with digest): gcr.io/cloud-builders/docker
    Sending build context to Docker daemon  40.43MB

    Step 1/10 : FROM node:10-alpine as build-step
    10-alpine: Pulling from library/node
    ddad3d7c1e96: Pulling fs layer
    de915e575d22: Pulling fs layer
    7150aa69525b: Pulling fs layer
    d7aa47be044e: Pulling fs layer
    d7aa47be044e: Waiting
    ddad3d7c1e96: Verifying Checksum
    ddad3d7c1e96: Download complete
    7150aa69525b: Verifying Checksum
    7150aa69525b: Download complete
    d7aa47be044e: Verifying Checksum
    d7aa47be044e: Download complete
    de915e575d22: Verifying Checksum
    de915e575d22: Download complete
    ddad3d7c1e96: Pull complete
    de915e575d22: Pull complete
    7150aa69525b: Pull complete
    d7aa47be044e: Pull complete
    Digest: sha256:dc98dac24efd4254f75976c40bce46944697a110d06ce7fa47e7268470cf2e28
    Status: Downloaded newer image for node:10-alpine
     ---> aa67ba258e18
    Step 2/10 : RUN mkdir -p /app
     ---> Running in 646a1564cb80
    Removing intermediate container 646a1564cb80
     ---> 67294f6ec083
    Step 3/10 : WORKDIR /app
     ---> Running in 199afd3b91f1
    Removing intermediate container 199afd3b91f1
     ---> 089af75a6a2b
    Step 4/10 : COPY package.json /app
     ---> e857fe951ed0
    Step 5/10 : RUN npm install
     ---> Running in d9ad09cd2206
    [91mnpm[0m[91m [0m[91mWARN deprecated core-js@2.6.12: core-js@<3.3 is no longer maintained and not recommended for usage due to the number of issues. Because of the V8 engine whims, feature detection in old core-js versions could cause a slowdown up to 100x even if nothing is polyfilled. Please, upgrade your dependencies to the actual version of core-js.
    [0m[91mnpm[0m[91m [0m[91mWARN[0m[91m [0m[91mdeprecated[0m[91m ini@1.3.5: Please update to ini >=1.3.6 to avoid a prototype pollution issue
    [0m[91mnpm[0m[91m [0m[91mWARN[0m[91m [0m[91mdeprecated[0m[91m uuid@3.4.0: Please upgrade  to version 7 or higher.  Older versions may use Math.random() in certain circumstances, which is known to be problematic.  See https://v8.dev/blog/math-random for details.
    [0m[91mnpm WARN deprecated request@2.88.2: request has been deprecated, see https://github.com/request/request/issues/3142
    [0m[91mnpm WARN deprecated chokidar@2.1.8: Chokidar 2 will break on node v14+. Upgrade to chokidar 3 with 15x less dependencies.
    [0m[91mnpm[0m[91m WARN[0m[91m [0m[91mdeprecated har-validator@5.1.5: this library is no longer supported
    [0m[91mnpm [0m[91mWARN[0m[91m deprecated fsevents@1.2.13: fsevents 1 will break on node v14+ and could be using insecure binaries. Upgrade to fsevents 2.
    [0m[91mnpm WARN deprecated querystring@0.2.0: The querystring API is considered Legacy. new code should use the URLSearchParams API instead.
    [0m[91mnpm [0m[91mWARN [0m[91mdeprecated[0m[91m urix@0.1.0: Please see https://github.com/lydell/urix#deprecated
    [0m[91mnpm WARN deprecated resolve-url@0.2.1: https://github.com/lydell/resolve-url#deprecated
    [0m
    > core-js@3.6.4 postinstall /app/node_modules/@angular-devkit/build-angular/node_modules/core-js
    > node -e "try{require('./postinstall')}catch(e){}"

    [96mThank you for using core-js ([94m https://github.com/zloirock/core-js [96m) for polyfilling JavaScript standard library![0m

    [96mThe project needs your help! Please consider supporting of core-js on Open Collective or Patreon: [0m
    [96m>[94m https://opencollective.com/core-js [0m
    [96m>[94m https://www.patreon.com/zloirock [0m

    [96mAlso, the author of core-js ([94m https://github.com/zloirock [96m) is looking for a good job -)[0m


    > @fortawesome/fontawesome-common-types@0.2.36 postinstall /app/node_modules/@fortawesome/fontawesome-common-types
    > node attribution.js

    Font Awesome Free 0.2.36 by @fontawesome - https://fontawesome.com
    License - https://fontawesome.com/license/free (Icons: CC BY 4.0, Fonts: SIL OFL 1.1, Code: MIT License)


    > core-js@3.16.2 postinstall /app/node_modules/@syncfusion/ej2-angular-base/node_modules/core-js
    > node -e "try{require('./postinstall')}catch(e){}"

    [96mThank you for using core-js ([94m https://github.com/zloirock/core-js [96m) for polyfilling JavaScript standard library![0m

    [96mThe project needs your help! Please consider supporting of core-js:[0m
    [96m>[94m https://opencollective.com/core-js [0m
    [96m>[94m https://patreon.com/zloirock [0m
    [96m>[94m https://paypal.me/zloirock [0m
    [96m>[94m bitcoin: bc1qlea7544qtsmj2rayg0lthvza9fau63ux0fstcz [0m

    [96mAlso, the author of core-js ([94m https://github.com/zloirock [96m) is looking for a good job -)[0m


    > @angular/cli@9.0.7 postinstall /app/node_modules/@angular/cli
    > node ./bin/postinstall/script.js


    > @fortawesome/fontawesome-free@5.15.4 postinstall /app/node_modules/@fortawesome/fontawesome-free
    > node attribution.js

    Font Awesome Free 5.15.4 by @fontawesome - https://fontawesome.com
    License - https://fontawesome.com/license/free (Icons: CC BY 4.0, Fonts: SIL OFL 1.1, Code: MIT License)


    > @fortawesome/fontawesome-svg-core@1.2.36 postinstall /app/node_modules/@fortawesome/fontawesome-svg-core
    > node attribution.js

    Font Awesome Free 1.2.36 by @fontawesome - https://fontawesome.com
    License - https://fontawesome.com/license/free (Icons: CC BY 4.0, Fonts: SIL OFL 1.1, Code: MIT License)


    > @fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons@5.15.4 postinstall /app/node_modules/@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons
    > node attribution.js

    Font Awesome Free 5.15.4 by @fontawesome - https://fontawesome.com
    License - https://fontawesome.com/license/free (Icons: CC BY 4.0, Fonts: SIL OFL 1.1, Code: MIT License)


    > core-js@2.6.12 postinstall /app/node_modules/core-js
    > node -e "try{require('./postinstall')}catch(e){}"

    [96mThank you for using core-js ([94m https://github.com/zloirock/core-js [96m) for polyfilling JavaScript standard library![0m

    [96mThe project needs your help! Please consider supporting of core-js on Open Collective or Patreon: [0m
    [96m>[94m https://opencollective.com/core-js [0m
    [96m>[94m https://www.patreon.com/zloirock [0m

    [96mAlso, the author of core-js ([94m https://github.com/zloirock [96m) is looking for a good job -)[0m

    [91mnpm WARN lifecycle portfolio@0.0.0~postinstall: cannot run in wd portfolio@0.0.0 ng build --prod --aot=false --build-optimizer=false (wd=/app)
    [0m[91mnpm notice created a lockfile as package-lock.json. You should commit this file.
    [0m[91mnpm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@~2.3.2 (node_modules/chokidar/node_modules/fsevents):
    npm WARN [0m[91mnotsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@2.3.2: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"linux","arch":"x64"})
    [0m[91mnpm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@^1.2.7 (node_modules/watchpack-chokidar2/node_modules/chokidar/node_modules/fsevents):
    npm WARN notsup[0m[91m SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@1.2.13: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"linux","arch":"x64"})
    [0m[91mnpm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@^1.2.7 (node_modules/webpack-dev-server/node_modules/chokidar/node_modules/fsevents):
    npm WARN notsup[0m[91m SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@1.2.13: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"linux","arch":"x64"})
    [0m[91mnpm WARN[0m[91m @angular/flex-layout@9.0.0-beta.31 requires a peer of @angular/core@>=9.1.5 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
    [0m[91mnpm WARN @angular/flex-layout@9.0.0-beta.31 requires a peer of @angular/common@>=9.1.5 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
    [0m[91mnpm WARN @angular/flex-layout@9.0.0-beta.31 requires a peer of @angular/platform-browser@>=9.1.5 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
    [0m[91mnpm WARN bootstrap@4.6.0 requires a peer of popper.js@^1.16.1 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
    [0m[91mnpm WARN ng-circle-progress@1.6.0 requires a peer of @angular/common@>=9.1.0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
    [0m[91mnpm WARN ng-circle-progress@1.6.0 requires a peer of @angular/core@>=9.1.0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
    [0m[91mnpm WARN @syncfusion/ej2-angular-base@17.4.55 requires a peer of @angular/common@4.10.0 - 9.0.2 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
    [0m[91mnpm WARN @syncfusion/ej2-angular-base@17.4.55 requires a peer of @angular/compiler@4.10.0 - 9.0.2 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
    [0m[91mnpm WARN @syncfusion/ej2-angular-base@17.4.55 requires a peer of @angular/core@4.10.0 - 9.0.2 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
    [0m[91mnpm WARN @syncfusion/ej2-angular-base@17.4.55 requires a peer of @angular/forms@4.10.0 - 9.0.2 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
    [0m[91mnpm WARN @syncfusion/ej2-angular-base@17.4.55 requires a peer of @angular/platform-browser@4.10.0 - 9.0.2 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
    [0m[91mnpm WARN @syncfusion/ej2-angular-base@17.4.55 requires a peer of @angular/platform-browser-dynamic@4.10.0 - 9.0.2 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
    [0m[91m
    [0madded 1426 packages from 1188 contributors and audited 1431 packages in 58.941s

    64 packages are looking for funding
      run `npm fund` for details

    found 51 vulnerabilities (6 low, 39 moderate, 5 high, 1 critical)
      run `npm audit fix` to fix them, or `npm audit` for details
    Removing intermediate container d9ad09cd2206
     ---> 72cf28fa5a7c
    Step 6/10 : COPY . /app
     ---> 034e3b8864cb
    Step 7/10 : RUN npm run build --prod
     ---> Running in 6df23cb16fa5

    > portfolio@0.0.0 build /app
    > ng build --prod --aot=false --build-optimizer=false

    [91m
    Compiling @angular/core : es2015 as esm2015
    [0m[91m
    Compiling @angular/common : es2015 as esm2015
    [0m[91m
    Compiling @angular/platform-browser : es2015 as esm2015
    [0m[91m
    Compiling @angular/platform-browser-dynamic : es2015 as esm2015
    [0m[91m
    Compiling @angular/flex-layout/core : es2015 as esm2015
    [0m[91m
    Compiling @angular/flex-layout/extended : es2015 as esm2015
    [0m[91m
    Compiling @angular/cdk/bidi : es2015 as esm2015
    [0m[91m
    Compiling @angular/flex-layout/flex : es2015 as esm2015
    [0m[91m
    Compiling @angular/flex-layout/grid : es2015 as esm2015
    [0m[91m
    Compiling @angular/flex-layout : es2015 as esm2015
    [0m[91m
    Compiling @angular/forms : es2015 as esm2015
    [0m[91m
    Compiling @angular/common/http : es2015 as esm2015
    [0m[91m
    Compiling ng-circle-progress : es2015 as esm2015
    [0m[91m
    Compiling @kolkov/angular-editor : es2015 as esm2015
    [0m[91m
    Compiling @angular/cdk/platform : es2015 as esm2015
    [0m[91m
    Compiling @angular/cdk/collections : es2015 as esm2015
    [0m[91m
    Compiling @angular/cdk/scrolling : es2015 as esm2015
    [0m[91m
    Compiling @angular/cdk/portal : es2015 as esm2015
    [0m[91m
    Compiling @angular/cdk/keycodes : es2015 as esm2015
    [0m[91m
    Compiling @angular/cdk/overlay : es2015 as esm2015
    [0m[91m
    Compiling @angular/cdk/observers : es2015 as esm2015
    [0m[91m
    Compiling @angular/cdk/a11y : es2015 as esm2015
    [0m[91m
    Compiling @angular/animations : es2015 as esm2015
    [0m[91m
    Compiling @angular/animations/browser : es2015 as esm2015
    [0m[91m
    Compiling @angular/platform-browser/animations : es2015 as esm2015
    [0m[91m
    Compiling @angular/material/core : es2015 as esm2015
    [0m[91m
    Compiling @angular/material/button : es2015 as esm2015
    [0m[91m
    Compiling @angular/cdk/layout : es2015 as esm2015
    [0m[91m
    Compiling @angular/material/snack-bar : es2015 as esm2015
    [0m[91m
    Compiling @fortawesome/angular-fontawesome : es2015 as esm2015
    [0mGenerating ES5 bundles for differential loading...
    ES5 bundle generation complete.

    chunk {0} runtime-es2015.8bae5995e99ee7582e6c.js (runtime) 1.46 kB [entry] [rendered]
    chunk {0} runtime-es5.8bae5995e99ee7582e6c.js (runtime) 1.46 kB [entry] [rendered]
    chunk {1} main-es2015.dc6fe7e8995cc1772a16.js (main) 1.35 MB [initial] [rendered]
    chunk {1} main-es5.dc6fe7e8995cc1772a16.js (main) 1.4 MB [initial] [rendered]
    chunk {2} polyfills-es2015.a4660fc436b698b2ca29.js (polyfills) 61.3 kB [initial] [rendered]
    chunk {3} polyfills-es5.6b5ee25874ec64f1745e.js (polyfills-es5) 136 kB [initial] [rendered]
    chunk {4} styles.365c7f153c5be2a5f7d1.css (styles) 205 kB [initial] [rendered]
    chunk {scripts} scripts.b11bb42cb75a53297f18.js (scripts) 104 kB [entry] [rendered]
    Date: 2021-08-19T12:35:49.946Z - Hash: dd3cb71f17750c7a2cea - Time: 313326ms
    Removing intermediate container 6df23cb16fa5
     ---> d4a281a3f947
    Step 8/10 : FROM nginx:1.17.1-alpine
    1.17.1-alpine: Pulling from library/nginx
    e7c96db7181b: Already exists
    3fb6217217ef: Pulling fs layer
    3fb6217217ef: Verifying Checksum
    3fb6217217ef: Download complete
    3fb6217217ef: Pull complete
    Digest: sha256:17bd1698318e9c0f9ba2c5ed49f53d690684dab7fe3e8019b855c352528d57be
    Status: Downloaded newer image for nginx:1.17.1-alpine
     ---> ea1193fd3dde
    Step 9/10 : COPY --from=build-step /app/dist/swift-media /usr/share/nginx/html
     ---> 85b317d701b2
    Step 10/10 : EXPOSE 80
     ---> Running in 643de67acbe8
    Removing intermediate container 643de67acbe8
     ---> 355605b29dc5
    Successfully built 355605b29dc5
    Successfully tagged gcr.io/swift-media-322516/github.com/lewismorgans/portfolio:79c27520b788b3631ca0eece3a6107502df402ed
    PUSH
    Pushing gcr.io/swift-media-322516/github.com/lewismorgans/portfolio:79c27520b788b3631ca0eece3a6107502df402ed
    The push refers to repository [gcr.io/swift-media-322516/github.com/lewismorgans/portfolio]
    57057b8da8c4: Preparing
    fbe0fc9bcf95: Preparing
    f1b5933fe4b5: Preparing
    f1b5933fe4b5: Layer already exists
    fbe0fc9bcf95: Layer already exists
    57057b8da8c4: Pushed
    79c27520b788b3631ca0eece3a6107502df402ed: digest: sha256:480416113eff892f18ecd86706bd7ccfdd36fdf8d132c2b32aa4541b03e52ddc size: 951
    DONE
```

Dockerfile:

````
RUN mkdir -p /app
WORKDIR /app
COPY package.json /app
RUN npm install
COPY . /app
RUN npm run build --prod
FROM nginx:1.17.1-alpine
COPY --from=build-step /app/dist/swift-media /usr/share/nginx/html
EXPOSE 80```
````

Comment: Could you share the error logs / stacktrace

Comment: Thanks, I've added the log file from google.

Comment: thx ! these are the logs for the passing build. What about the error message / stack saying the `the build has failed`

Comment: The container can build successfully but the files that you put in it can contain errors. I'm not front end expert, but there might have something wrong in the JS generation. You can pull your container locally and run it in interactive mode. Like that, you can inspect what you have, and what are the potential issues inside. You can also try to run the container locally to reproduce the error and debug more efficiently!

Comment: I do not think the build has failed. The deploy has failed. Your Dockerfile does not show a process being started listening on the Cloud Run port (defaults to 8080). For Node.js, you need a line similar to this at the end of your Dockerfile: **CMD [ "node", "index.js" ]**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned by @[John Hanley](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68848131/google-cloud-run-docker-building-container-building-but-not-accessible#:%7E:text=%20the%20deploy%20has%20failed.). There is no issue with the Build, that's why there are no errors in the logs. The problem is inside the container you made. You can use the [quickstart](https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/quickstarts/build-and-deploy/nodejs?hl=en#containerizing) from the Google documentation to follow it as an example. There you can see that your Dockerfile lacks some parameters.

Here is how it should look:

````
RUN mkdir -p /app
WORKDIR /app
COPY package.json /app
RUN npm install
COPY . /app
RUN npm run build --prod
FROM nginx:1.17.1-alpine
COPY --from=build-step /app/dist/swift-media /usr/share/nginx/html
EXPOSE 80```
CMD [ "node", "index.js" ]
````

If you are a complete noob I would recommend you to check out the mentioned quickstart and to take a look to the other [code samples](https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/samples?hl=en) available to get used to Cloud Run.